# Using PHP retrieved variables in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I will use the following javascript to display a Google Map Window in a webpage.

```
<script language = 'javascript'"> 
    function initialize() 
    {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
      {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(35.904173, 14.433396), 16);
        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    } 
</script>
```

I would like to read the coordinates from a db, to generate the map using PHP, but how is it possible to use the retrieved(eg $lat = xxx and $lon = yyy) values into the javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a hard insert?

```
<script language = 'javascript'"> 
    function initialize() 
    {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
      {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$lon; ?>), 16);
        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Use ajax to retrieve the values

2) Embed the PHP in your javascript:

```
<script language = 'javascript'"> 
    function initialize() 
    {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
      {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lon; ?>), 16);
        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I think that latitude should be the first parameter :-)